# How to calculate the attractive force in a gravitational field in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I believe that a gravitational field has energy, as Weinburg wrote in his textbook [Gravitation and Cosmology](http://clearwalksoft.com/science-geography/43590-cosmology.html), on page 171: "... ... the gravitational field does carry energy and momentum." As long as two points in space have energies, they attract each other. Now consider two particles in the gravitational field of the Earth. I want to calculate the attractive force between these two particles, not due to their own mass or energy, but due to the gravitational field of the Earth. Following is what I have done.

First, I found the stress-energy tensor of the gravitational field, on page 165 of Weinburg's book:
\begin{equation}
t_{\mu k} \equiv \frac{1}{8\pi G} [R_{\mu k} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu k} {R^{\lambda}}_{\lambda} - {R^{(1)}}_{\mu k} + \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu k}{R^{(1)\lambda}}_{\lambda}]           \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $R_{\mu k}$ is Ricci tensor;
\begin{equation}
{R^{(1)}}_{\mu k} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial^{2} {h^{\lambda}}_{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{k}} - \frac{\partial^{2} {h^{\lambda}}_{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu}\partial x^{k}} - \frac{\partial^{2} {h^{\lambda}}_{k}}{\partial x^{\lambda}\partial x^{\mu}} + \frac{\partial^{2} h_{\mu k}}{\partial x^{\lambda}\partial x_{\lambda}})            \tag{2}
\end{equation}
is the part of the Ricci tensor linear in $h_{\mu\nu}$, and
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} - \eta_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
is the difference between the metric of the curved space and Minkowski metric.

Next, on page 36 in Zee's textbook [Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell](https://www.academia.edu/22862175/_In_a_Nutshell_Princeton_A._Zee_Quantum_Field_Theory_in_a_Nutshell_Princeton_University_Press_2010_), I found the interaction between two lumps of stress energy:
\begin{equation}
W(T) = -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}} T^{\mu\nu}(k)^{*} \frac{(G_{\mu\lambda}G_{\nu\sigma} + G_{\mu\sigma}G_{\nu\lambda}) - \frac{2}{3} G_{\mu\nu}G_{\lambda\sigma}}{k^{2} - m^{2} +i\epsilon}T^{\lambda\sigma}(k)                                       \tag{3}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\frac{(G_{\mu\lambda}G_{\nu\sigma} + G_{\mu\sigma}G_{\nu\lambda}) - \frac{2}{3} G_{\mu\nu}G_{\lambda\sigma}}{k^{2} - m^{2} +i\epsilon}
\end{equation}
is the propagator for a massive spin-2 particle.
As stated in Zee's book, from the conservation of energy and momentum $\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}(x) = 0$ and hence
$k_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}(k) = 0$, we can replace $G_{\mu\nu}$ in (3) by $g_{\mu\nu}$, which can be further approxmiated by $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ for the gravitational field of the Earth. Look at the interaction between two lumps of energy density $T^{00}$, we have from (3) that
\begin{equation}
W(T) = -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}} T^{00}(k)^{*} \frac{1 + 1 - \frac{2}{3}}{k^{2} - m^{2} +i\epsilon}T^{00}(k)                                       \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Applying (4) to my problem, i.e., calculating the attraction between two particles in the gravitational field of the Earth, $T^{00}(k)$ should be the energy density of the gravitational field of the Earth at the positions of these two particles. This energy density is given by (1), which is a complicated function of the metric and has nothing to do with $k$, the momentum of the propagating spin-2 particle (graviton).  So, looking at (4), the integral seems divergent. I am stuck. How should I do the calculation?

Comment: You are mixing quite different approximations. If you want to calculate the effect on the force between particles due to gravitational field of the Earth you cannot use the flat space propagator in an integral but instead must use Green function calculated for curved spacetime (generally no momentum space integral would be possible). Also, the limit $m\to 0 $ of [massive gravity is singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_gravity#The_vDVZ_discontinuity).

Comment: @A.V.S. - I considered the Earth as a Schwarzschild geometry, its metric (time component) is computed to be $g_{00} = -1 + O(10^{-9})$. So it is quite safe to approximate it as Minkowski metric. Am I right?

Comment: Of course, for most things. But you are trying to find interaction between regions with weak gravitational field (self-energy of gravitational field of the Earth). This would be the higher order effect. Care must be taken when dropping small terms or the effect would either disappear or be completely different. For instance why would you assume that the stress energy is given only by $T^{00}$?

Comment: For the gravitational field of the Earth, the energy density at a certain point in space is all what it has (due to this field, barring other matters). Isn't this not true?

Comment: If I do not take approximations but use the exact expression in (3), the whole interaction would be zero because $G_{\mu\nu} = 0$ for Schwarzschild geometry. This is an even more serious problem which I don't know how to cope with. But I don't believe the interaction is zero because there is energy in the gravitational field and two points must attract each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111007/discussion-between-a-v-s-and-shen).